# angular 2 unmet peer dependencies

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 project created through CLI and my package.json looks like following:

```
{
  "name": "thesis-proto",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.25",
    "angular2-mdl": "^2.13.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdl-stepper": "^1.1.6",
    "ng2-tour": "^0.1.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I am trying to install ng2-tour (https://isaacplmann.github.io/ng2-tour/) when I get following error:

[image]

What exactly I should do? I do not want to break any existing dependencies.

Comment: you need to update the `angular to version 4`

Comment: Looks like both `ng2-tour` and `@ng-bootsrap` are expecting Angular ^4.0.3. Your option is to either roll back those packages to older ones or upgrade your core `@angular` packages to match the dependency.

Comment: @Aravind upgrading to angular4 wouldn'r break anything?

Answer (score 0):

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY error is thrown when the dependencies of one or more modules specified in the package.json file is not met. Check the warnings carefully and update the package.json file with correct versions of dependencies.

Then run

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```

This will install all the required dependencies correctly.